# Why won't the catch block run?

Tags: java

I have the following method to write an array to a text file. If a existing text file is given then it works fine but if a file that doesn't exist is given neither try-catch will run the code to restart the method. I'm not given any error or anything but the catch block won't run. I didn't think i would need to catch for an IOException but the code won't even run if i don't do that. So yea, anyone know how i can get this to work?

Edit: Forgot to mention the getInput method prompts the user for input.

```
private static void openFileWriter(String prompt, boolean append, int wordsperline, String[] story) {
  try {
    try {
      save = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(getInput(prompt), append));
      wordsperline = 0;
      save.println("");
      save.println("");
      save.println("Story start");
      for (int x = 0; x <= story.length-1; x++) {
        if (story[x] == null) {
        } else {
          if (wordsperline == 21) {
           save.println(story[x]);
           wordsperline = 0;
          } else {
           save.print(story[x]);
           wordsperline++;
          }
        }
      }
      save.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
    openFileWriter("File not found", append,wordsperline,story);
    } 
  } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    openFileWriter("File not found", append,wordsperline,story);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [`FileWriter` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29).

Quoting from the constructor doc:

> Throws:
>       IOException - if the named file exists but is a directory rather than a regular file, does not exist but cannot be created, or cannot be opened for any other reason

If you pass it a filename that doesn't exist, but is a legal filename in a location where you have permission to write, it simply creates the file.

Your code in fact does reach the catch blocks if you pass it a directory (somewhat oddly, it catches a `FileNotFoundException` in this situation for me rather than the documented `IOException`).

To check if a file exists, see [`File` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists%28%29)

Answer (score 2):

If the File does not exist you cannot write to it, in your catch block you are trying to write the error to the File that doesn't exist. Also, I think you only need 1 catch block here, and note that one of the if statement blocks is empty.

try this:

```
try
{
    save = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(getInput(prompt), append));
    wordsperline = 0;
    save.println("");
    save.println("");
    save.println("Story start");
    for(int x = 0; x <= story.length-1; x++)
    {
        if (story[x] == null)
        {
        }
        else
        {
           if (wordsperline == 21)
           {
             save.println(story[x]);
             wordsperline = 0;
           }
           else
           {
             save.print(story[x]);
             wordsperline++;
           }
       }
    }
    save.close();
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e1)
{
   System.err.println(e1.getMessage());
}   
catch (IOException e)
{
   System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: In my catch block im calling the method again so that the user can attempt to enter a new text file (The getInput method prompts the user for input, should of mentioned that)

Comment: In any case whatever code i put in the catch blocks doesn't run at all

Comment: How do you determine code in catch blocks are not run at all?

Comment: The method doesn't run again and ive attempted to print lines (including the suggested one above). In every case nothing takes place.

Comment: @JKJones If the code in the catch block(s) isn't executing, that tells me no exception was thrown. Can you post how you call this method the first time?

Comment: Do you want me to post the entire main method or just where i do the call?

Comment: @JKJones: you might as well post the whole `main` method!!

Comment: You NEVER want to call a method that just failed from its catch block. Think about it. Its reaching the `catch` block because you're method failed to run correctly. Restarting you're method from there can only lead to bad things.

Comment: @Brendan He mentioned above in the comments that the method prompts the user for a file name. So each time through the method a new file open is attempted

Comment: But the only reason that it fails to run correctly was because the user entered a file name that doesn't exist. When i call it again and if the user enters a file that exists it won't fail to run correctly again. Also Hunter you're right the exception isn't being thrown. If i enter "" as the file name the exception is thrown and the method is called again like its supposed to. Any idea why entering a non-existing file doesn't result in a FileNotFoundException?

Comment: @Hunter McMillen Ah, I was posting this and never noticed that, though it is still good practice to not re-call a method which just failed

Comment: Is there a way to check if a file exists? I suppose i could put a for loop in have it stop looping when the given file exists?

Comment: @JKJones You could create a `File` object from the user input then use the `File.exists()` method on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this version and send the stack trace when you get the exception:

```
public static List<String> splitByLength(String filename, int length) {
    List<String> splitWords = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i += length) {
        splitWords
                .add(str.substring(i, Math.min(str.length(), i + length)));
    }
    return splitWords;
}

private static void openFileWriter(String prompt, boolean append,
        int wordsperline, String[] story) {
    PrintWriter save = null;
    try {
        save = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("c:\\test.txt", append));
        wordsperline = 0;
        save.println("");
        save.println("");
        save.println("Story start");
        for (int x = 0; x <= story.length - 1; x++) {
            if (story[x] != null) {
                List<String> splitWords = splitByLength(story[x], 21);
                for (String line : splitWords) {
                    save.println(line);
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (save != null) {
            save.close();
        }
    }
}
```